# Convex Independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence, economics

I have a difficulty in understanding a given definition for convex independence:

> A set of beliefs $\beta$ of an agent $i$ satisfy convex independence if beliefs of no type $t_i$ can be represented as a convex combination of other types $t'_i \neq t_i$

I read the Wikipedia article about convex combinations and I think I get what it means. Thus, also the definition of convex independence should be clear but I can't make sense of the given example:

[example of convex independence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx6Js.png)

- why does convex independence fail for the bottom example? I can't see how I can create a convex combination (of the red row?) to match another row (belief)
- what is the fastest way to check for convex independence in such a case? Checking each row vs. the other ones would take quite some time

Notation:

$\beta_i(.) = \pi_j(.)$: belief of player i (expressed as a probability) about player $j$ being of a certain type given his own type

$\theta_1^i$: type „$\theta_1$“ of player $i$

Comment: You'll have to explain to us the notation in that image before expecting an answer. But visually, it's clear that it's not convex independent because there are three collinear points.

Comment: For the second question, try the [Quickhull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull)

Comment: @JairTaylor I added the notation to the question. Thanks a lot for looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you show has a failure of convex independence because you can write $\beta_i(\theta^i_2) = (\beta_i(\theta^i_3) + \beta_i(\theta^i_2))/2$. Ignoring the obscure economic decision theory notation, what they say is simply that $(1/5, 3/10, 5/10) = ((1/5, 1/5, 3/5) + (1/5, 2/5, 2/5))/2$.
The fastest way to check for independence by hand is by Gaussian elimination.

Comment: But this would only show that these two rows are not linear independent, right?
As far as I understand it, convex independence is a less stringent requirement than linear independence. In case of a convex combination, all coefficients added up must be equal to 1 and must be part of the interval [0,1]. That's not the case here? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @asdf1234 Because the weights are $1/2$, the example contradicts convex independence as well. If the weights were general (not positive and adding to 1) then we would only contradict linear independence. (If your question was about finding convex independence by hand, you have to find all cases of linear dependence and then see if one of them is convex dependence.)

Comment: thanks a lot, I got it :)